# Alternatives for routing two pinouts to the same RJ12

Tags: pcb-design, layout, esd, tvs

I’m working on a project that is basically UART, power and a couple of I/Os over a RJ12 connector.
I want to be able to interact with two different devices that have the same interface but with different pinouts.

My idea towards a solution is to jumper the RJ12 with zero-ohms in two configurations where one of them would be DNP. The question then arises how to lay this out to make ESD protection work.

My plan is to put the TVS array after the 0-ohms so that I would always protect the same MCU pin with the same TVS. But the trace between the connector and the TVS would have to go through the 0-ohm, with a bit of twisting and turning to get the signals from the correct pins to match.

Is this likely to cause problems?

Are there other solutions? Like a digital mux that can handle both signals and power?

Are there any open source projects that does this where I can get inspiration?

Thanks!

[edit]
First attempt is something like this. I'd be happy to get some feedback on this.
[image: first attempt]

Comment: Can you expand on why you think "the trace between the connector and the TVS would have to go through the 0-ohm, with a bit of twisting and turning" would be problematic?

Comment: @brhans I don’t know that it would be problematic but all the literature I find on the subject says to place the TVS really close to the connector.